# Problema ao concatenar arquivos csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Estou tentando concatenar um arquivo csv com outro. O meu objetivo é retirar dados de um HTML diariamente e minha rotina deveria pegar um arquivo csv chamado de 'dado_antigo' onde se encontra um dataframe salvo em csv, e quando rodasse novamente deveria criar um novo arquivo atualizado e concater esse arquivo novo com o antigo. Após isso acontecer ele deveria apagar os dados repetidos e adicionando só os novos para o arquivo csv, criando um novo 'dado_antigo' para que amanhã a rotina rode novamente.
Estou usando:

```
#a.to_csv('dado_antigo.csv')
b = pd.read_csv('dado_antigo.csv', 
                index_col='Data',
                parse_dates= ['Data'])
#arquivo concatenado
c = pd.concat((b,a))
aa, bb = np.unique(c, return_index=True)
c = c.ix[bb]
c = pd.read_csv('dado_antigo.csv')
```

E recebo este erro:

> IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds

Como poderia resolver?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Baseando-me no pandas versão 0.20.1, existe uma função chamada `pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates` aqui na [documentação](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) que pode te ajudar.

Você pode fazer assim, por exemplo:

`df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['1', '2']], columns=['A', 'B'])`

`df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['5', '6'], ['7', '8'], ['1', '2']], columns=['A', 'B'])`

`res = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)`

`res = res.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)`

O resultado em `res` deve conter o que você precisa.

**Atenção:** O `.reset_index(drop=True)` não é necessário, mas eu aconselho fortemente, pois sem ele o seu frame vai ter os índices fora de ordem e isso pode te causar problemas dependendo do que você queira fazer depois.

Espero ter ajudado.